# How can I stop this Perl command from printing XML declarations over and over again?

Tags: linux, perl

I'm runing the following command in Red Hat Linux:

```
perl -ne '
    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    while(/(<PRINTKIT FORM_ID=\"PP_WELCOMEKIT\">.*?<\/PRINTKIT>)/g){
        print "<sf><XDF>$1</XDF></sf>"
    };
' $1 > $2.$TS2.postscrub
```

`$2` is a file name and `$TS2` is just a date.

Currently it prints out like 100 lines of

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
```

when I actually don't want it to print any at all.

Can someone change the code above to do everything it is doing except not print `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>` anymore? I have already tried just removing the print statement with that line like follows:

```
perl -ne '
    while(/(<PRINTKIT FORM_ID=\"PP_WELCOMEKIT\">.*?<\/PRINTKIT>)/g){ 
        print "<sf><XDF>$1</XDF></sf>"
    };
' $1 > $2.$TS2.postscrub
```

Doing this makes it output a 0 byte file so I know it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't. That's `xml` being done by a `regex` and that's nasty. Give us an example of your source and desired output, and we'll give you a solution that's much less horrible.

Comment: This is something that has been set up for my company in the back end for a long time. I'm thinking all its trying to do is remove the printkit tags and replace them with the sf and XDF tags.

Comment: And that's exactly why it's a bad idea - for all the reasons you're now having problems with it. Regular expressions can't do `XML` properly.

Comment: I think whoever wrote that forgot to use a `BEGIN` block. `-n` will run the commands once for each line of input, so you're printing a new XML declaration for every single line in the input file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -ne'
    BEGIN { print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"; }
    while(/(<PRINTKIT FORM_ID=\"PP_WELCOMEKIT\">.*?<\/PRINTKIT>)/g){
        print "<sf><XDF>$1</XDF></sf>"
    }
' $1 > $2.$TS2.postscrub
```

or

```
perl -ne'
    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" if $. == 1;
    while(/(<PRINTKIT FORM_ID=\"PP_WELCOMEKIT\">.*?<\/PRINTKIT>)/g){
        print "<sf><XDF>$1</XDF></sf>"
    }
' $1 > $2.$TS2.postscrub
```

or

```
perl -e'
    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    while (<>) {
        while(/(<PRINTKIT FORM_ID=\"PP_WELCOMEKIT\">.*?<\/PRINTKIT>)/g){
            print "<sf><XDF>$1</XDF></sf>"
        }
    }
' $1 > $2.$TS2.postscrub
```

Answer (score 7):

Really - please don't use regular expressions for manipulating `XML`. It's very very nasty and as you've discovered - prone to breaking inexplicably.

Try something like this instead ( I have made a guess at your sample data ).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub replace_printkit {
    my ( $twig, $pk ) = @_;
    my $sf = $twig->root->insert_new_elt('sf');
    $sf->insert_new_elt( 'XDF', $pk->trimmed_text );
    $pk->delete;
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented',
    'twig_handlers' => { 'PRINTKIT' => \&replace_printkit }
);

$twig->parse( \*DATA );
$twig->set_xml_version('1.0');
$twig->set_encoding('utf-8');
$twig->print;


__DATA__
<xml>
  <PRINTKIT FORM_ID="PP_WELCOMEKIT">some_stuff_here</PRINTKIT>
</xml>
```

This prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <sf>
    <XDF>some_stuff_here</XDF>
  </sf>
</xml>
```

You may have to amend it slightly for your input data.

Edit:

> When you use $twig->print can I place this into a file? If so what is the command to do so?

```
open ( my $output_fh, '>', "new_file.xml" ) or die $!;
print {$output_fh} $twig -> sprint;
close ( $output_fh );
```

Comment: When you use $twig->print can I place this into a file? If so what is the command to do so?

Comment: When I try to run this program I get the following: Can't locate XML/Twig.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /export/home/strsadm/scripts/scrubFiles.pe line 6.

Comment: `$twig -> sprint` returns the `XML` as a string. So you can open a file and print that out. See edit.

Answer (score 4):

The advisability of using regexes for XML aside, the simple answer to this question: "How can I stop this Perl command from printing XML declarations over and over again?" is to wrap the XML declaration in a `BEGIN` block.

```
BEGIN { print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" }
```

[**perlrun**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) describes the effect of the `-n` switch:

> causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it    iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk

```
    LINE:
    while (<>) {
    ...     # your program goes here
    }
```

So whatever you put in the body of an `-n` program will be run for each line of input, thus repeatedly printing the XML tag. It won't do that if you wrap it with BEGIN.

However, `-n` behavior is *so* established for Perl, and repeating the XML tag is so non-standard for XML, it's a wonder this has ever fit anybody's idea of a solution. I would almost suspect that somebody who didn't know what it was doing, removed the `BEGIN` block, simply because it's such an obvious candidate for one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave the parameter -n. It adds a while loop around your code. You just have a working while loop, change it to read all lines (`while (<>)`) and you can put your condition after your print statement, like this:

```
perl -e '
    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    while(<>) {
        print "<sf><XDF>$1</XDF></sf>" if(/(<PRINTKIT FORM_ID=\"PP_WELCOMEKIT\">.*?<\/PRINTKIT>)/g);
    };' $1 > $2.$TS2.postscrub
```